# What's difference between TextFrame and TextFrame2 in Microsoft.Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

[The TextFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.textframe?view=excel-pia)

[The TextFrame2](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.textframe2?view=excel-pia)

And I couldn't tell the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the COM world once an interop interface is published it will never be modified.

Whenever an update is needed then a new interface will be created usually with an index appended to the end of the original name.

As you can see

- they have different properties and methods (and also different `GuidAttribute`)
- `TextFrame` can only be used in `Shape` objects
- `TextFrame2` can be used in `Shape`, `ShapeRange` and `ChartFormat` objects

So unless you need something that exists only in `TextFrame` I would suggest to use `TextFrame2`.